# VMware compile local file failed?

Tags: ubuntu, g++, vmware

im running ubuntu on Vmware and have a local folder mapped so the virtual machine can access the files. The "real" files are localed under D:/something and appear in Ubuntu uder root/mnt/hgfs/something

However, whenever i try to compile a cpp file using g++ i get a linker error. This error does not appear when i try to compile the same file if it was in the root directly.

Please help!

error msg: /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Illegal seek
colect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue, which was fixed in the 3/28/2011 release of the VMware vmhgs driver. More information here: 
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.vmware.tools.devel/745